# loading simulation data from a dataframe of lists into a multi-index in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a more efficient way of capturing stock price simulation and associated metrics (option price, option delta etc.) in a dataframe. Here's the code:

```
def bscall_val(S0, strike, sigma, ttm, rf):
    d1 = (np.log(S0/strike) + 0.5 * np.power(sigma, 2) * ttm )/(sigma * np.power(ttm, 0.5))
    d2 = d1 - sigma * np.power(ttm, 0.5)                                                                
    bs_call = S0 * stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1) - strike * exp(-r * ttm) * stats.norm.cdf(d2, 0, 1)
    return bs_call       

def bscall_delta(S0, strike, sigma, ttm, rf):
    d1 = (np.log(S0/strike) + 0.5 * np.power(sigma, 2) * ttm )/(sigma * np.power(ttm, 0.5))
    bscall_delta = stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1)
    return bscall_delta

def sim_results(strike, sigma, ttm, r, numSteps, numPaths, quantity):
    dt = ttm/numSteps
    
    path = np.zeros((numSteps, numPaths))
    delta = np.zeros((numSteps, numPaths))

    path = simpath(S0, sigma, ttm, numSteps, numPaths)
    delta = bscall_delta(path, sigma, ttm, numSteps, numPaths)



    sim_results = pd.DataFrame( {'path' : [path],
                                 'delta' : [delta]

                                })
   return sim_results

S0 = 100
strike = 100.05
# t = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
# M = dt.datetime(2022, 6, 1)
ttm = 1
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.80
numSteps = 10
numPaths = 2
mu = 0
# ttm = (M - t).days/365
epsilon = 0.02
quantity = 10000

sims = sim_results(strike, sigma, ttm, r, numSteps, numPaths, quantity)
sims['path']
```

---

This runs fine, but the resulting dataframe consists of lists of the outputs for the variables I want - the price path and the delta.....which won't work.

Couple of ways I was trying to tackle this:

1. One thought was to convert each variable into a dataframe early on and concat the resulting dataframes. I will experiment with that shortly.....but before I do that....
2. Is there a way to easily expanding the current dataframe into one with each list broken into its own column (e.g. path should have two columns and so should the delta - this is a function of the numPaths variable)? I've seen some examples....but those involve static column names...whereas mine can change.
3. Is there a way of putting the data into a multi-index such that each simulation is captured on its own "axis" ? E.g. I * [J] * K, where I would be numSteps, J would be the numPaths for each variable (so 4 in the current selection) and K would be the third axis capturing I and [J] for each simulation result?

Would appreciate some guidance!
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this rather inelegant way to get this to work:

```
def sim_results(strike, sigma, ttm, r, numSteps, numPaths, quantity):
    dt = ttm/numSteps
    

    path = simpath(S0, sigma, ttm, numSteps, numPaths)
    delta = bscall_delta(path, sigma, ttm, numSteps, numPaths)

    cpth = []
    cdel = []

    for i in range(0, numPaths):        
        cpth.append('path_' + str(i))
        cdel.append('delta_' + str(i))   

    path = pd.DataFrame(path, columns = cpth, index=range(0, numSteps))
    delta = pd.DataFrame(delta, columns = cdel, index=range(0, numSteps))


    sim_results = pd.concat([path, delta], axis=1)

   return sim_results

S0 = 100
strike = 100.05
# t = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
# M = dt.datetime(2022, 6, 1)
ttm = 1
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.80
numSteps = 10
numPaths = 2
mu = 0
# ttm = (M - t).days/365
epsilon = 0.02
quantity = 10000

sims = sim_results(strike, sigma, ttm, r, numSteps, numPaths, quantity)
sims['path']
```

It works.....but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.